# Jar is not loading resources file

Tags: java

I have a project with a folder "src/main/resources" where inside there is the hibernate configuration file, I load it using this line of code

```
HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cgf.xml").getPath()
```

From inside the IDE it is working well, but when I create the jar it doesn't file the file.

How can I load it properly in the jar file too?

Thanks

Comment: The line of code you provided only gets the path of the file - how are you using this path?

Comment: My hibernate class needs the path of the file for reading the structure of my mapped JPA

Comment: Can you provide the code of your hibernate class?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("fileName").getFile());
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for ceratin that this is the issue without knowing how exactly you use the path extracted by:

```
HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cgf.xml").getPath()
```

but I can tell you this:

Run from an IDE the above line of code will return:

```
/path/to/project/src/main/resources/hibernate.cgf.xml
```

which is a valid filesystem path. You can then use this path to, for example, create an instance of `File` class and then use that instance to read the file contents.

However the same line of code run from inside a jar file will return:

```
file:/path/to/jar/jar_name.jar!/hibernate.cgf.xml
```

which is not a valid filesystem path. If you create an instance of `File` class using this path and then try to read the contents of the file you'll get an exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundExeption`

To read the contents of the file from inside of a jar you should use method `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`, which will return an instance of class `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.JarURLInputStream` (or equivalent in non-Oracle or non-OpenJDK Java). You can then use this object to read the contents of the file. For example:

```
InputStream inputStream = HibernateUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/hibernate.cgf.xml");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
String fileContents = scanner.hasNext() ? sscanner.next() : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the file is absent from the jar you create. There's too little information in your question, but I will try a guess:

Your hibernate.cgf.xml resides in the same directory as the Java sourcefles, and you are using a build tool (be it IDE, maven, gradle or an ant script) that expects resources to be stored in a separate directory.

It's easy to check: try to unzip your jar and see if the file is there (use any tool, you can just change the extension from .jar to .zip). I think you will see the file is absent.

Then come back with a question: "how to pack my non-java resources into a jar, using XXX", where XXX will be the name of the techology you are using for building the jar.

Comment: Yes I did check, the files are in the jar, obviously they are in the root directory since once the jar is created the folder src/main/resources will not be present in it

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the slash in `"/hibernate.cgf.xml"` is not needed, if the `hibernate.cgf.xml` is in the same package as you class HibernateUtil.

You can access the file actually also via the classloader using the full path. Yet you never add to it the first slash.

Here is some code demonstrating how you can access the file using different methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Accessing via class
    System.out.println(SimpleTests.class.getResource("hibernate.cgf.xml").getPath());
    // Accessing via classloader from the current thread
    String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResource("simple/hibernate.cgf.xml").getPath();
    System.out.println(path);
    // Accessing via classloader used by the current class
    System.out.println(SimpleTests.class.getClassLoader().getResource("simple/hibernate.cgf.xml").getPath());
}
```

In the example above the package 'simple' should be replaced by the package where your `hibernate.cgf.xml` is. But you should never have the slash at the beginning of the package declaration.

Comment: Thank you, I have already tried via classLoader but yet it's not working, the jar says files are missing

Comment: @Chrix1387 And you removed the initial slash?

Comment: Yes, with getResources I put the slash, via classLoader I remove it, via IDE it works fine in both ways but the jar doesn't. If I open it with winrar I can see the resources files in the root together with libraries

Comment: @Chrix1387 It might be that you have another jar file with the same package which is loaded first.